# Shopify liquid sections JSON template: Setting 'excludedHandles' value must be an array

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

In a section i'm using for the page builder / theme customiser, i'm making use of the product_list setting (https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/architecture/settings/input-settings#product_list). This allows for a selection of multiple products. I'm using this to exlude these handles from a earlier chosen collection.

The output of this in JSON is the following:

```
      "type": "section-builder-product-list",
      "settings": {
        "collection": "elixirs",
        "excludedHandles": "minerals,mineralien-banane,wilde-krauter-pulver,mineralien-passionsfrucht,kurkuma-ritual,matcha-ritual,magnesium-complex"
      }
    },
```

Unfortunately, i receive following error in my CLI:

Setting 'excludedHandles' value must be an array.

How do i counter this?

Answer (score 0):

Format `excludedHandles` like that :

```
  "type": "section-builder-product-list",
  "settings": {
    "collection": "elixirs",
    "excludedHandles": [
      "minerals",
      "mineralien-banane",
      "wilde-krauter-pulver",
      "mineralien-passionsfrucht",
      "kurkuma-ritual",
      "matcha-ritual",
      "magnesium-complex"
    ],
```